# A face of a thousand masks

Tags: riddle

For every question you might ask
Five answers might I give
Despite my ever-changing mask
No err will you forgive

I may appear a fickle host
But we’re both keeping score
From the side, I will riposte
And you’ll be back for more

For posterity, I will protect
Your quests within a picture
So quicker than you could expect
The student becomes the teacher

*What am I?*

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Stack Exchange

For every question you might ask
Five answers might I give

> or more & more...

Despite my ever-changing mask

> different people answering each time

No err will you forgive

> downvote!

I may appear a fickle host
But we’re both keeping score

> votes

From the side, I will riposte
And you’ll be back for more

For posterity, I will protect
Your quests within a picture

> maybe user profile

So quicker than you could expect
The student becomes the teacher

> Someone who came to ask might as well find themselves answering...

Comment: From the side, I will riposte: The jabs here come from the comments ("on the side"), but they won't stop you from coming back for more!  For posterity... within a picture: The Q&As are saved forever to be indexed by search engines.

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps a

> Search engine

many answers on one question

fickle host

> the information isn't really his, just elsewhere on the web

keeping quests

> caching search queries

student becomes teacher -

> crawls the internet for data, then presents it on the search

Comment: Warmer.  The answer is more specific and fits every line.

Answer (score 0):

My best guess is...

> A Computer

Seems to fit. You can search with it and get a mess of answers, constant evolution (pc, laptop, phones, watches), very easy to blame the computer ("this thing is so slow!"), it keeps score and tracks your 'quests' in a monitor while playing games, and finally because a user (student of a computer) can become a developer (teacher of computers).

Comment: You're thinking in the right direction, but the answer I have in mind fits closely throughout the riddle.  It should be an obvious "yes" once it's found.

Comment: @Xodarap777 - That's how I try to write riddles too! No red herrings, just obscure references.